# Are there any observable effects of casein binding to capsaicin?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, food-chemistry

I would like to complete an experiment on balancing capsaicin. Since both capsaicin and milk are bases on the pH scale, I prefer not to use the common term "neutralizing".

I will be extracting the capsaicin and I do not wish to taste-test it. Is the bound casein protein with the hydrophobic capsaicin oil visible? Will it curdle in order for me to obtain quantifiable amounts?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the casein, not the fat, in milk that neutralizes the heat from capsaicin?  Also, keep in mind that "neutralizing" capsaicin just means preventing it from binding to a G-protein coupled receptor in your mouth.  Since GCPRs are proteins, all that needs to happen for it to be "neutralized" is that it needs to bind to or stick to something more strongly than it sticks to GCPRs in your mouth.

Comment: Capsaicin is very oil-soluble. Most of the things that "neutralise" the perceived hotness are actually ways of moving the compound into the oil phase of a mixture (which is what I think happens in milk) so that less of it is stuck in the heat receptors where its effect is felt.

Comment: Also, the Oleic acid found in milk [is an inhibitor of TRPV1](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms13092) (aka, the capsaicin receptor).

Answer (score 1):

Capsaicin doesn't dissociate in water and can't act as a base (like well-known bases such as Sodium Hydroxide or Ammonia) and won't react with the casein in milk. So there won't be any curdling/precipitation of casein protein. Casein will precipitate through pH adjustment if you lower its pH to the isoelectric point (from 6.6 to 4.6).

Notes:

- Casein isn't a base, neither an acid, it has an amphoteric nature.
- Bases generally don't react with each other.
- Pure capsaicin is a powder, not an oil.